# How to Standard Coding base on Magento Architecture For Query optimization

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, coding-standards, speedoptimization, magento-coding-standard

How to Optimization magento1 & 2 default Products, Order, Customer, Wishlist etc.. collection query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This post will help you for best coding standard, How to follow Magento standard.

Please download this PDF and understand the Magento flow and how it's work and learn.

[Download PDF](https://bhaveshgodhani.wordpress.com/2021/12/08/how-to-standard-coding-base-on-magento-architecture-for-your-site-optimization/)

Follow this thread also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124077/3723

Note: PDF for Magento 1 but it will help you for Magento 2 as well.